# How to make emacs show short (not full) file path in minibuffer on save?

Tags: emacs, save, minibuffer

The problem is when file path is pretty long each time I save it, minibuffer height grows and basically immediately shrinks. Kind of annoying because happens so often.

So I want to either shorten (basename?) the "wrote: ..." message or make default (starting) minibuffer height of 2 lines. Or maybe enable truncation in minibuffer only but that's not really good.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** I just noticed the `message-truncate-lines` variable and, unlike `resize-mini-windows` and `max-mini-window-height`, I can actually make this one behave the way I want:

```lisp
(defadvice save-buffer (around my-save-mini-window-size)
  "Don't increase the size of the echo area if the path of the file being saved is too long to show on one line."
  (let ((message-truncate-lines t))
    ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'save-buffer)
```

*original answer follows (and I'm interested to know why setting the other variables with similar advice doesn't have the desired effect, if anyone can elaborate on that?)*

I think messing with the message itself is going to be pretty hairy (and in any case a bad idea). `write-region` (in fileio.c) does say of its arguments `If VISIT is neither t nor nil nor a string, that means do not display the "Wrote file" message`, but I strongly doubt that enforcing that would be sensible.

I think the only sane approach is to prevent the minibuffer from resizing regardless of the message length. The following will do this, but for more situations than just saving a file:

```lisp
(setq resize-mini-windows nil)
```

My normal approach here would be to write some around advice for the function we're interested in (I was thinking `save-buffer`), to temporarily set that value, but for whatever reason that's not having the desired effect.

Similarly with using `before-save-hook` and `after-save-hook` to set and restore it.

There's also the `max-mini-window-height` variable, but that appears to be subject to the same issue when attempting to set it temporarily.

Comment: Thanks, works! :) At least as a temporary solution. Regarding max-mini-window-height it only controls max-height and sadly there's no counterpart for min-height. Accept in a couple of days (just in case).

Comment: Yay, even better, cool! Well I'm happy, thank you very much for you time.) Little bit weird there isn't more obvious and straightforward to deal with that.